# Check if file exits using Shell Script -Follow multiple code paths

Tags: macos, shell, installation, sh

My Main application takes time to launch due to a non correctable bug in the framework i have used.I have created a launcher program that simply displays a loading animation and does the background work(one time) and after doing that the main app loads.

I dont have any success in creating an installer package that executes a post installer script.Is there a way i can check if the loader was executed once using a shell script.In the first launch i plan to create a dummy file and in subsequent launches the script check if this file is there.If its there the main program will be launched instead of the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, how and what your loader is. However, in your loader or the script that launches the loader, try writing the PID for the loader when it runs :

echo $! > run.pid

To check if your loader has run/executed first time, in your shell script, just check if the run.pid file exists :

if [ -f run.pid ]
then
    launch the main program
else
    // do something
fi

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.Followed a similar approach and got it running.